# How to configure nginx on Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, configuration

I am new to nginx and tried some tutorials to configure nginx on Amazon Linux 2. For a simple start I tried to show just another html page instead of the welcome page of nginx. The problem is thats no matter what changes I do in the nginx.conf file. Nothing change. The most confusing part is even if I stop nginx the welcome page is stil available. I started a new ec2-instance a moment ago and I did the following:

`sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx`

`sudo systemctl start nginx`

Now the welcome page is available with the amazon url: ec2-**-**-***-***.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.

`sudo systemctl stop nginx`

systemctl status shows that nginx is dead but the welcome page is still available. I am really confused, it seems didnt understand some fundamentals about nginx. Something similar happened if I change the nginx.conf file (for example I comment the complete server body out) and restart nginx. Nothing changed, the welcome page is still available...

best regards

Comment: It's maybe the cache. If you press shift and the row to restart, are you keep watching the welcome page?

Comment: Perhaps there are multiple copies of nginx installed on your system, or multiple config files?

Comment: Yeah wow okay the problem was the cache. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Perhaps the tutorials already installed apache so it is apache that is showing the webpage. This is what has happened to me in the past.

Answer (score -2):

`sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: Also, please add some explanation.